# Using CSS Calc Function inside of Translate

Tags: css

Currently I'm trying to use the CSS `calc()` function inside of a `transform: translate`, but I'm not having any luck.

```
transform: translate((calc(100vw/4))px, (calc(100vh/8))px) scale(1.333)
```

Is this nor possible, or is my syntax just all wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you can convert the calc result to px afterwards...

Comment: Yes you are right. I removed the px outside of the calc function and started seeing movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc you need to mix values like this.

```
width: calc(100% - 80px);
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I think I assumed it worked closer to jQuery where the ending unit is placed outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to just fix the syntax? Like

`transform: translate(((calc(100vw/4))px), (calc(100vh/8))px) scale(1.333)`

Comment: Well that's what I was wondering. If my syntax was wrong or if it just doesn't work. Turns out it was the removal of the px that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering if we can use `calc()` inside a transform, the answer is **yes, we can**.

### How to use the calc() function?

To learn how to use it properly it's best to [read the MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

### Will it work everywhere?

The answer is no. There are a couple of know issues:

> - Firefox does not support width: calc() on table cells.
> - Firefox <48 does not support calc() inside the line-height, stroke-width, stroke-dashoffset, and stroke-dasharray properties.
> - IE & Edge are reported to not support calc inside a 'flex'. (Not tested on older versions).
> - Safari & iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units (vw, vh, etc) in calc().
> - IE11 does not support transitioning values set with calc().
> - IE11 is reported to not support calc() correctly in generated content.
> - IE11 is reported to have trouble with calc() with nested expressions (i.e. it rounds differently).
> - IE10, IE11, and Edge < 14 don't support using calc() inside a transform.
> - IE 9 - 11 don't render box-shadow when calc() is used for any of the values.
> - IE10 crashes when a div with a property using calc() has a child with same property with inherit.
> - IE 9 - 11 and Edge do not support width: calc() on table cells.
> - Firefox does not support calc() on color functions.

Source: [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc).